# geom = pg.built_in.Geometry() and the it says there is no attribute "built_in"

Tags: python, geometry

I'm trying to update a code done in 2018 (not by me) and i fell on `geom = pg.built_in.Geometry()` and it says there is no attribute "built_in".

```
import pygmsh as pg
geom = pg.built_in.Geometry()
AttributeError: module 'pygmsh' has no attribute 'built_in'
```

How is the updated version, or is there anything else I can do?

While looking on the internet I found a few changes that didn't even work,
Like using geom = pg.Geometry() straight

Comment: Check your version of the `pygmsh`   then refer to the doc https://pypi.org/project/pygmsh/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`built_in` was removed in `pygmsh 7.*` versions. Try

```
import pygmsh

with pygmsh.geo.Geometry() as geom:
    ...
```